# Show spinner on HTML5 Geolocation request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

I have a button in a html webpage and it will get the `Geolocation` details after a click on that button, may be the request will process for about `5 seconds`, so it's good to show a spinner or loading message to the user to indicate their request is processing.

This is what I tried.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    //request starts Showing the spinner at this point.

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        //get coordinates

    }, function (error) {
        // Handle errors !!This callback isn't execute if a user close the 
        // geolocation prompt or click on `Not Now` option in the prompt

        // So its not always correct to hide the spinner in here.

    }, {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 8000});
}
```

Hiding the spinner in `errorCallback` is not always correct because of This callback isn't execute if a user `close` the `Geolocation prompt` or click on `Not Now` option in the prompt as below image.

[image]

What is the best possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery Spinner its more reliable.

http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/loading%20spinner/

Comment: sorry this question is not about spinners